# How to configure SCP for AWS RDS service to manage snapshots while restricting users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I want to create an SCP which protects RDS snapshots. Only users having a custom role called *RDS-Admin* should be able to delete the snapshots.

Everything is working as expected, but the automatic snapshots are also not getting deleted after the retention period if I apply this SCP. Need a scalable solution that can be used to allow the RDS service also to delete the snapshots after the defined retention period.

Below is the SCP I have created, which allows users with the mentioned role will be able to delete snapshots.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
     {
      "Sid": "DenyDeleteSnap",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "rds:DeleteDBSnapshot",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:rds:us-west-*:*:snapshot:*",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnNotLike": {
          "aws:PrincipalArn": [
            "arn:aws:iam::*:role/aws-reserved/sso.amazonaws.com/us-west-2/AWSReservedSSO_RDS-Admin_*"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The Principal Arn of the RDS service component that deletes snapshots after retention period ends, will not by your SSO RDS Admin role.  It will be some service role for RDS.  Check in your cloudtrail logs, you may be able to get the role principal there from the (failed) removal attempts.

Comment: Yes, it will not be an SSO RDS-Admin role. I have an RDS administrator who assumes this RDS-Admin role and allows him to delete the snapshots. 

But I want to add an additional condition allowing the RDS service to delete automatic snapshots after the retention period. When I verified the CloudTrail logs, I saw no related information.